# Howto enable WindowsAzure remote desktop with Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, azure, remote-desktop, webrole

What's the easiest way to enable WindowsAzure remote desktop with Eclipse?
I use the WindowsAzure4e Plugin to develop a PHP WebRole.

**EDIT:**

I think I found something:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2010/12/29/azure-home-part-13-remote-desktop-configuration.aspx

I'll give it try.

**EDIT2:** It worked. See also this [link](http://blog.itopia.de/windowsazure-remote-desktop/303).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're on the right path. If I get some bandwidth this weekend I'll see if I can't get you the exact steps for that toolkit.